# Codeigniter классы

Tags: ооп, классы, php, codeigniter

У меня написана библиотека, определяющая статус пользователя на сайте по его id или текущей сессии.

Она прописана в autoload и доступна в любом классе.
В проекте множество контроллеров (классов), в которых приходится однотипно создавать такое, чтобы получить статус авторизированного пользователя.

```
private $user_status = '';
$this->user_status = $this->mylibrary->GetStatus();
```

Как избежать дубликатов?

Comment: Не знаю как в CI, но по идее, классы должны наследоваться от какого - то основного. На пример, все контроллеры наследуются от какого - то  класса Controller. Вот в основном классе и объяви эту переменную. она будет доступна во всех наследуемых классах.

Comment: Да, есть такое, это ядро фреймворка...были бы еще варианты

Comment: Я слабо знаком с CI, но в контроллере не должно быть никаких сведений о пользователе. Можно сделать некий реестр сведений о пользователе, доступный глобально (если его нет) и дергать его. Когда вы замечаете, что начинаете повторять код в разных местах - это верный признак того, что нужно перестраивать архитектуру.
В Yii, например, можно без проблем отнаследовать класс пользователя и добавить туда дополнительный функционал, никак не меняя текущий.